# can figure out why i am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chart.js

hi i am trying to draw chart.js line chart using the csv data , i am a total beginner in html and javascript and i have been trying to get the chart js read csv data to plot lines , and finally came close to getting something , but ended up getting the error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`
Error count just keep on increasing :

[image]

i have searched and read many posts regarding this issue but still can't figure out whats wrong with the code.

Here is the code in question :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
   
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git1.min.js"></script>
     <script>
            $(document).on('change','.fx',function(){
       //var widget = changeFX(this.value);
        document.getElementById('content').src = "chart1.html?value="+this.value;
        document.getElementById('content').style.display = "block";
       });
</script>
<style>
  iframe{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
  }
</style> 
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column"  >
   <select name="fx" class="fx">
    <option value="EURUSD">EURUSD</option>
    <option value="EURJPY">EURJPY</option>
    <option value="EURGBP">EURGBP</option>
</select>
<iframe src="chart1.html"   id="content" >
</iframe>
<div>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      const makeChart = async () => {
        const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
        const csvData = await getData();
    setInterval(csvData,1);
        const { dataLabels, columnFive, columnSix } = csvData;
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: "line",
          data: {
            labels: dataLabels,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Long Lots",
                data: columnFive,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "green",
         pointRadius: 0,

              },
              {
                label: "Short Lots",
                data: columnSix,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "red",
        pointRadius: 0,
          gridLines: {
                lineWidth: 0
            }
              },
            ],
          },
        });
      };
      window.addEventListener("load", makeChart);
      const getData = async () => {
        const data = await fetch("http://localhost:46920/myfile.csv", { mode: 'no-cors' }).then((res) => res.text());
        const dataLabels = [];
        const columnFive = [];
        const columnSix = [];
        const rows = data.split("\n");
        rows.map((row) => {
          const cols = row.split(",");
          dataLabels.push(cols[0]);
          columnFive.push(parseFloat(cols[5]));
          columnSix.push(parseFloat(cols[6]));
        });
        return { dataLabels, columnFive, columnSix };
      };
    </script>
 </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is what i am currently getting in terms of chart :

[image]

**I will highly appreciate the help**

**Update1:** clicking on the error and then clicking on the index.html dont do anything and the errors just keep on increasing (error count)

[image]

Comment: Click on the link in the console error to see what line it takes you to.

Comment: My only guess is that your browser doesn't support async functions (ES2017). That's probably the most recent syntax used. However, the message is logged over 7 thousand times, which suggests some loop somewhere.

Comment: hi @VLAZ thank you for taking time to read the post , i am using Opera , are you sure that opera doesnt allow async function ?

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, i have updated the OP , clicking on the error does nothing , i am guessing its because of the error count still growing ?

Comment: @Sanders I'm not - it was a guess. [can I use](https://caniuse.com/async-functions) says that all operas except Mini support it. Mini is basically irrelevant.

Comment: With the update, the issue seems to be that you try to execute `csvData` as a `setInterval` callback but I doubt it's a function.

Comment: @VLAZ what i dont understand is , when i was trying the chart js code in a separate html file , everything was working perfectly and it was reading and updating chart accordingly , but when i add it in the index.html , it doesnt work and give me error s